# Intel XDK App designer theme contradictory behavior

Tags: intel-xdk

I've designed an app for a local store everything is working great it's just that the standard theme is behaving oddly. I'm using the App designer UI framework with default theme and Device native option selected. But no matter what option I select the default theme stays like [image: this which is black]
though the theme looks like [image: this]
in the designer view. The button color with 'green' class set also doesn't appear as green. This happens on android only. Anybody else encountered this?

Comment: You are seeing the App Framework standard theme there. When you switch to the emulator, you are seeing the native view for android.  this is working correctly. If you only want one theme, do not select "native view" and select one of the themes from the dropdown.

Comment: That was my point, even though I set other themes, the dark one above is what I always see, no matter which theme.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's been a change in App Framework such that it requires setting `$.ui.useOSThemes = false`.  It seems that by default, it wil go with the theme it thinks is similar to whatever device it's running on, so if you tried it on the emulator and the device is set to an Android device, it will always look like "Android Dark", ditto for testing on a real device.  To avoid that default, you need to set `useOSThemes` to `false`.  This will need to be fixed in the App Designer, but in the meantime you can add this line at the end of your head section (right before `</head>`):

```
<script>$.ui.useOSThemes = false</script>
```

At least that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks I'd already solved that. I'd like to add one more thing, App designer is creating an appframework 2.1 directory and not adding the 2.1 js files but older in it. I kept getting could not set property 'useOSThemes' of undefined and finally figured it was using older libraries so I added the new ones and it worked. Also it should be noted, to set the theme to whichever device is desired, that should be done via js/jquery in ready event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Ian Maffet has the answer.

You have chosen the "Device Native" theme in App Designer.  That means the appearance will change depending upon the device.  When you go to Android, you see it looking like  Android.  In App Designer itself, which is not a device, it just uses the default App Framework theme.

If you want to know in App Designer what it might look like, briefly choose a device theme. For example, choose Android Dark and you'll see the same thing you are seeing in the Emulator.

If you want what you are seeing now in App Designer to be what it looks like on the device, choose the "App Framework" theme.

As to the green button, that green style is 'suppressed' by Android Dark. That's not a bug, that is the expected behavior. You can see that in App Designer as well if you activate the Android Dark theme choice.